# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, segmentation-fault

I've never seen a SegFault in PHP before today, but apparently it's possible. At first I thought it was mysql driver, but it turned out it was my code ;).

I spent about 2 days debugging my code and finally tracked it down to it's cause (so to all you future PHP programmers who run into this, you are welcome!)

Long story short, you **CAN'T do an `unset()` on the same array your are walking while you're doing `array_walk()`.**

The purpose is to eliminate all elements from $this->votes that don't exist in the $out array (where the key of $this->votes matches to the id property of one of the elements in $out).

**The Problem** I was having was about half the time the code would run fine, and the other half it would crash with a Segmentation Fault in the apache log (making it pretty hard to debug because it was a while until I noticed this error).

And yea, it's a pretty poorly thought out piece of code to begin with....

```
    array_walk($this->votes, function(&$o, $key) use($that, $out) {
        $found = array_filter($out, function($p) use($key) {
            return $p['id'] == $key;
        });

        if(count($found) == 0) {
            unset($this->votes[$key]); //very very bad!!!!
        }
    });
```

Comment: Segmentation faults are usually caused by a installation of PHP not compiled on the right system, modules, or by bugs. Thanks for sharing your experience!

Comment: @John: I know, that's what I thought at first! That's why I was trying to blame it on mysql driver or old php install (which is what every other article I found described). But as you can see you CAN cause a segfault with your OWN code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, what ends up happening is `unset()` messes up the `$this->vote`s array length. `array_walk` uses an iterator which expects the `$this->votes` array to remain the same length throughout the entire walk. If I wrote my own `array_walk` function (`for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->votes); $i++`) it would just throw an undefined index notice. But since we are using `array_walk` it will actually try to look in a location in memory which may or may not have some data. This can cause the unpredictability of the function (sometimes the code can run just fine, other times it will cause a seg fault).

So the RIGHT way to do it would be

```
    $tmpVotes = array();
    array_walk($this->votes, function(&$o, $key) use($that, $out, $tmpVotes) {
        $found = array_filter($out, function($p) use($key, $that, $tmpVotes) {
            return $p['id'] == $key;
        });

        if(count($found) > 0) {
            $tpmVotes[$key] = $o;
        }
    });

    $this->votes = $tmpVotes;
```

From PHP Manual:

> Only the values of the array may potentially be changed; its structure cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, **unset** or reorder elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable.

If anyone has a better way of explaining what happens here, please post!

Comment: seems to work [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HoUiEb), but for some reason not all keys are removed (but it does work as expected in php 5.3.10)

Comment: yeah I guess that's another example of "unpredictable" behavior. Maybe  because my array elements were arrays themselves it caused the segfault.

Comment: Kind of odd for people to instantly answer their own questions. But I'll give you a hint: `--enable-debug` and `gdb`

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Leigh. I actually didn't have root access on the server that was having this problem (and couldn't replicate the problem on my local machine). But next time we have a weird bug like this I def. will tell the server admins to install gdb. And the reason for instantly answering my own question is because it really was a huge problem I had (I had no idea what part of my code was causing it and I couldn't find resources which gave hints at solving it). But now that I figured it out, I'm sure someone somewhere will eventually run into this issue.